# Anycubic printer gives a "hotend not heating up" error

Tags: hotend, temperature

I just bought an Anycubic 3D printer and after a few uses the screen on the printer would say "hotend not heating up".

The heat bed and hotend would not heat up all the way and would cool faster than heating up when I enabled a print.

What do I do?

Comment: Hi Dartless08, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Which anycubic printer did you buy?

Answer (score 1):

As it is brand new, contact the seller.

If it wasn't brand new, but years into service, you could troubleshoot why it is not heating up, e.g. loose contact, bad heater element, thermistor faulty, etc..